# how can I make label inside scrollable panel fixed

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have  below scrollable panel

```
scrollablepanel: {
            viewTemplate: {
                layout: 'center',               
                header: false,              
                scrollable: true,               
                items: {
                    xtype: 'itemsview'
                }
            }
        }
```

And this panel has two items: label and toolbar as below

```
items: [{
        xtype: 'label',
        html: "title"
    },
    {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        reference: "titletoolbar",
        layout: "vbox",
        autoScroll: true,
        flex: 1,
        padding: 2,
        margin: 0,      
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function () {
                var me = this;
                var tool = me.up('titleview');
                tool.getController().updatetoolbar();
            }
        }
    }]
```

I want to make label inside the panel fixed on scroll. Right now its scrolling up along with the toolbar. can someone please help me with this?

Comment: can you share a fiddle with a reproducible example?

Comment: Without further information, I would say you could A) wrap it in a parent container with the label OR B) try [docked](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.Label.html#cfg-docked) items OR C) position it [floated](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.Label.html#cfg-floated). Sidenote: Never ever use getController(). This would give your view access to the controller and that is not part of MVVM. In your example you could add the afterrender logic to the controller anyways or use databinding ;)